# Swift - Dynamic number of buttons in tableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dynamic, uibutton

Actually i have a project in [github](https://github.com/titopalito/DynamicCellHeightAndDynamicButtonsProgrammatic). The problem is that i cannot get why when scrolling, the buttons constraints  in the cells are going crazy..
I didn't saw any project like this, then i have a reason to share it but i want to give a good example for another people.
I'll be very thankful with any help that drives me to the solution of this problem.
Best regards.
There it is the code for the cell:

```
import UIKit

class BookTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

let nameLabel = UILabel()
let detailLabel = UILabel()

var cellButton = UIButton()
var cellLabel = UILabel()
var book : Book!

// MARK: Initalizers
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}

func configureCellCon(botones:Int, titulo:String, book:Book) {
    self.book = book
    let marginGuide = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
    // configure titleLabel
    contentView.addSubview(nameLabel)
    nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    nameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    nameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    nameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    nameLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    nameLabel.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 16)
    nameLabel.text = book.name

    // configure authorLabel
    contentView.addSubview(detailLabel)
    detailLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    detailLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    //        detailLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    detailLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    detailLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabel.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    detailLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    detailLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 12)
    detailLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    detailLabel.text = book.details

    var lastButton = UIButton()
    if(book.buttonsAttibutes.count == 1) {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.tag = 0
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(white: 0.9, alpha: 0.0)
        //            button.setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor.white, forState: .normal)
        //            button.setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor.blue, forState: .normal)
        button.setTitle(book.buttonsAttibutes[0].title, for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.7), for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.init(white: 0.8, alpha: 1), for: .highlighted)
        button.layer.borderWidth = 0
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        contentView.addSubview(button)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addConstraints([
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .leftMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .leftMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .rightMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .rightMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -20),
            ])
        button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailLabel.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(mostrarMensaje), for:.touchUpInside)
        return
    }else if(book.buttonsAttibutes.count == 0) {
        detailLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        return
    }

    if(book.buttonsAttibutes.count > 0) {
        for x in 0...(book.buttonsAttibutes.count - 1) {
            let button = UIButton()
            button.tag = x
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(white: 0.9, alpha: 0.0)
            //            button.setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor.white, forState: .normal)
            //            button.setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor.blue, forState: .normal)
            button.setTitle(book.buttonsAttibutes[x].title, for: .normal)
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.7), for: .normal)
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.init(white: 0.8, alpha: 1), for: .highlighted)
            button.layer.borderWidth = 0
            button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
            contentView.addSubview(button)
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            //            button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            //            button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

            contentView.addConstraints([
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .leftMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .leftMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .rightMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .rightMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -20),
                ])

            if(x == 0){
                if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                    button.layer.cornerRadius = 8
                    button.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
                } else {
                    button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
                }
                button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailLabel.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            }else if(x == (book.buttonsAttibutes.count - 1)){
                if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                    button.layer.cornerRadius = 8
                    button.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
                } else {
                    button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
                }
                button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lastButton.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
                button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            }else{
                button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lastButton.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            }

            button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(mostrarMensaje), for:.touchUpInside)
            lastButton = button
        }
    }

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

@objc func mostrarMensaje(sender: UIButton){

    let message = self.book.buttonsAttibutes[sender.tag].message
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "\(self.book.name)", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cerrar", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
        (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    }

    alertController.addAction(okAction)
    if let myViewController = parentViewController {
        print(myViewController.title ?? "ViewController without title.")
        myViewController.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
} 
}
```

Comment: For the full code example you can look for the project at GitHub.

Comment: Storyboard ? U can try ?

Comment: I can't see reason why it shoudn't be crazy. You have few "shared" buttons and labels that you adding to different cells (mean views) simultaneously, and adding constraints to each of them. So those  views will settle in last cell shown. But have constraints to every cell. Then you for each cell you creating specific view and adding constraints to them as well.  But as table view will tend re reuse existed cells, you will add new view each time with removing existed. And new constraints.

Comment: PS: Ok, not shared, I thought you posted view controller, because usually it is responsibility of controller to configure cell. But you will have lot of conflicting crazy constraints anyway. Try to use InterfaceBuilder, it useful tool :) And StackViews.

Comment: What do You mean by "going crazy"?

Comment: @MichaelVorontsov thanks for your commentary, i'll try the that second way and will share it, i want to help people that wants to use something similar.

Comment: @HereTrix if you run the app with more "books", will see how the buttons loss their constraints. As says MichaelVorontsov, the cells apparently are being reused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i went for the "InterfaceBuilder" and did it properly.
However, I'll be reading more about programmatic methods to do it.
thanks to all of you for the guide.

When creating the buttons and constraints programmatically, they are generating more constraints over the same cells making them crash.